# What should a RESTful client do with its POST, PUT, or DELETE request upon a server error (500)

Tags: rest

I have a RESTful service that throws a 500 INTERNAL SERVER ERROR status upon an internal failure for a number of reasons: DB errors upon connectivity or field size, code bugs, or issues with a managed code call. The resulting unhandled exception is reported back by IIS as a 500. Is this an appropriate use of 500? It could imply "retry request" according to [MSDN Common REST API Error Codes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd179357.aspx). The proper API error code I am seeking is something like "### Server will NEVER process this request until a code change is made, do not resend or you will be looping forever and DOSing my server". Would a 400 Bad Request be more appropriate? It seems as if this is indicating a malformed request syntax itself, not that the service choked.

Furthermore, what should a client do when it encounters such an error? The server does not want another RESTful operation exactly like the previous one. The user may have spent some time doing data entry. Now we have to talk them off the ledge. Perhaps they can fix it on their own and that is the best practice? What are some similar experiences developers have had and how was it solved? Thanks.

Comment: What you 'should' do depends on who or what is consuming the error response.  What is the target audience for the error messages?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

4xx errors are "something is wrong with the client, they're sending the wrong stuff".

5xx errors are "something is wrong with the server, sorry it's out sick today."

Which basically means there's nothing the client can imply from a 5xx error. It could be permanent, it could be transient, the client doesn't know.

IIS sends a 500 error because IT doesn't know what happened. If your app is blindly throwing exceptions up to the web tier, there's not much more it can do or say about it.

If the server logic somehow actually KNOWS what's wrong, and WHEN it might be fixed, it can send a 503 error, telling the client it's unavailable and a Retry-After header telling the client when it will be back.

As for a client behavior, it's sort of dependent on the clients history with the service. Maybe the service intermittently fails with 500 errors, and another request will just work. This could happen, say, if you have a set of load balanced servers. The first server they hit is sick, but perhaps not sick enough that the load balancer has taken it out of rotation yet. So, another server may be just fine -- in that case the client could just retry and see what happens.

But in the end, it's up to the client as to what to do. It could try a simple back off algorithm. Retry once or twice. Retry once immediately, then again in 10s.

Or it could just push the 500 error back to the user with a polite message "tough luck".

Only the client use cases and requirements can really dictate what it's behavior should be when the server is dead.

Comment: This is helpful. I am trying to get a sense of what the consensus is for REST. The equivalent might be in SMTP land: the user gets a message back from the SMTP server or relay server that your email cannot be sent, and that is the end of it. If you resend, you will get the exact same error. So the client should be able to help the user out with the problem, or at bare minimum tell the user where to go.

Answer (score 1):

At the client side, we have to assume that the web-service is good, and that this either a malformed request (i.e. the user has keyed in something in-appropriate), or a network error of some kind. The method I used is to use an alert box, requesting the user to refresh the screen (F5), and try again with proper input. You may want to add "in case error persists, contact ...".